# unrecognized token '<' in json parse error

Tags: json, parsing, token, native

did't get any solution for unrecognized token `<` in json parse error when getting data through php from mysql to react native

code of native:

```
 login = () => {
      alert("go you");
      fetch('http://192.168.1.104/testmt.php',{
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
          'Accept':'application/json',
          'Content-Type':'text/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({
          namee:'teja'
        })
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      })

  }
```

code of php:

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','','trial'); 
if (!$link) { 

    echo json_encode('not done');
} 
echo ('hello');
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you run the PHP by itself? It sounds like it's either not being executed, or is throwing an error. Bear in mind that the `mysql_*` functions don't exist at all in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the php file is being served, the `<?php` on the first line is being parsed by the `fetch` handler that creates a `Response` object for you. When it encounters `<`in `<?php` you get this error.
The root cause of this may be with the web server, if you are using Apache the php module may not be loaded or the php handler not declared.

If you’re familiar with browser dev tools, check the network section and look for the request record from your `fetch` and inspect the response plain text response for a clue if the php source code was sent as I suspect

Comment: now i shifted and using it with the Xamp, but still the same output